# How to iterate over features in a filegdb - ogr Python

Tags: python, ogr, file-geodatabase

I'm trying to convert an Esri GDB terrain containing LiDAR data to a flat file structure (csv, xyz). Using ogr2ogr (with --explodecollections) is taking a long time (8 days so far to convert 40% of a 900GB terrain layer) - so while its grinding away, I'm exploring alternatives.

Each record in the terrain is a mulitpoint geometry with up to 3500 points. I'd like to test whether loading each record in the terrain to ogr memory, then exploding and writing to the flat file is more efficient than --explodecollections

My test code (so far) is below, but is failing while iterating through the features in the layer.

While iterating though each feature in the layer, so I have to 'unload' the geometry after each iteration, or am I referencing the geometry incorrectly?

```
from osgeo import ogr
# Open layer from GDB
gdb =  "source.gdb"'
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("FileGDB")
dataSource = driver.Open(gdb, 0)
layer = dataSource.GetLayerByName("DTM_1_MRFC")

print layer.GetName()

# Print field names
lyrDefn = layer.GetLayerDefn()
for i in range(lyrDefn.GetFieldCount()):
    print lyrDefn.GetFieldDefn(i).GetName()

# Features in layer
print "No of features: %d" %(layer.GetFeatureCount())

for feature in layer:
    fid = feature.GetFID()
    geom = feature.GetGeometryRef()
    geom_count = geom.GetGeometryCount()
    type = geom.GetGeometryName()
    # print fid
    print type
    print geom_count

# Clean close
del gdb
```

Comment: Why are you exploding the multipoints? The reason that the Esri tool for importing LiDAR in 9.x and 10.0 creates multipoints is because it's a more efficient way of storing the data... if you have a 900 GB Terrain it's likely to be 8+ TB as single point geometries! leading to a file that is so huge you can't do anything with it... why XYZ? it's the **worst format to store point information in** prone to corruption and loading failures and taking up so much drive space with uncompressed ASCII representations of numbers.. at least use WKB or LAS to store these records.

Comment: And you're doing this in python and are complaining that it's slow, if you want performance use GDAL/OGR in C# at least, C++ even better.

Comment: I agree with all your points - but as I'm not using ESRI software, its completely useless to me stored in a GDB. I need the data as xyz for input into hydraulic modelling software - for the 'production code', I'll add a spatial filter to once I can get it iterating correctly.  I intend to store the full dataset as a pgpointcloud type in PostGIS - multipoint storage similar to a terrain, just open source. But aside from philosophy about storage formats - do you know why it wont iterate?

Comment: Also - I'm not 'complaining that its slow' in python.  I'm saying its taking a long time using the command line on the entire dataset. Obviously I could add a spatial filter to the command line and only extract what I need - which would be more efficient as its using the C implementations - but I'd like to understand the process using python code - then I can add other steps to my processing pipeline as I develop it. My thought is that if the feature is in memory, other operations I undertake on it will be quick before i write it out to the end format (xyz, pgpointcloud, etc)

Comment: The efficiency of ogr2ogr is near optimal, you could get better performance for your specific task by not needing to support all output drivers; as YXZ is only text you could use printf("%d,%d,%d\n".. instead of layer->CreateFeature(*ogrFeature) but from a python point of view the more you rely on inbuilt functions the quicker generally your process will be, the overhead is mostly in the wrapping of the C object into a python object with applicable error checks. If you must use XYZ format consider tiling your data otherwise you'll likely crash whichever software is consuming your XYZ file.